# How can I sync iPhone photos one way?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, data-synchronization

Is it possible to configure my iPhone to just send Photos I have taken with the camera to iPhoto without synchronizing additionally stored photos back to the phone?

Answer (score 1):

At first you should disable Photo sync in iTunes. When you open iPhoto, you should be able to select your iPhone on the left side (assuming it's connected to your Mac). Then you can select all pictures you need and import them (you will even be asked if they will be deleted from your iPhone after the import). This way the iPhone should not sync photos like it ususally does with iTunes (when enabled).

See this Apple KB article: [Copying personal photos and videos from iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to your computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4083)

**EDIT:** You have to do this manually. I don't know if it's possible to do this automatically when syncing with iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

One way is this: plug in your phone, going to iTunes, click on the phone in the sidebar, and then click on the "Photos" tab. You'll see a "Sync photos from iPhoto" checkbox right at the top. Uncheck that.

If there are *some* photos that you'll want to carry around, one way to do that is to set up a manual photo album in iPhoto, and select that as the one photo album that you want to sync to the phone in iTunes. And obviously update that album as desired. I think that by default, your iPhone is set up to sync the "last import" photo album, which is how your photos are getting in. You can disable that in iTunes as above.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Photo Sync for your iPhone in iTunes, pick the second option (selected folders only) and don't select any folders/events/faces afterwards.